# Conexión con correo electrónico

Tags: java, conexión

Tengo un problema, resulta que el código que tengo no me está funcionando ya que es un código que permite tener conexión como el correo electrónico para poder renovar contraseña , confirmar cuenta , pero no me funciona , ¿alguien tienen un método que yo no sepa ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡Bienvenido Santiago! Por favor, en lugar de colocar imágenes, coloca el fragmento de código y el error a texto. [Edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/538598/edit) para colocar esos cambios. Puedes poner snippets de código encerrándolos entre tres comillas ``` codigo ```. En cuanto a tu pregunta, ¿Tienes antivirus? ¿Probaste desactivándolo? ¿Probaste cambiando el puerto a 465?

Comment: Muchas gracias jaime por la bienvenida, agradezco mucho tu asesoría y la calidez que brindas, lo voy hacer y te comentaré

Comment: Perfecto. Me comentas. No te olvides de editar tu pregunta. Una cosa que me intriga es que tienes como servidor gmail en el código pero en el error sale algo cómo `mail.foristom.org`. ¿Ese error corresponde a las propiedades que estás seteando? ¿No lo estarás seteando en otro lado? Algo no me cuadra en esas imágenes.

Comment: Me salió este error "javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.foristom.org, port: 465, response: -1 "

Comment: No sé por qué pones `smtp.gmail.com` cuando en realidad es `mail.foristom.org`. De cualquier forma, parece que  `mail.foristom.org` no tiene certificado válido. Establece entonces `"mail.smtp.starttls.enable"` a `"false"` y `"mail.smtp.ssl.enable"` a `"false"`. Deja el puerto como lo tenías antes e intenta con esos cambios que te dije.

Comment: Deberías quitar esa imagen y añadir el código en texto.